# How can I query a particular ID with sequelize.js so I can update it

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am working on a book library API where a user can borrow and update.

This is my logic for borrowing a book:

```
BorrowBooks(req, res) {
  Book.findOne({
      where: {
        title: req.body.booktitle,
        author: req.body.author,
      }
    })
    .then(book => {
      if (!book) {
        res.status(404).send({
          message: "Book not found!"
        })
      } else {
        return Borrower
          .create({
            booktitle: req.body.booktitle,
            borrowDate: Date.now(),
            returnDate: null,
            userId: req.params.userId,
          })
          .then(borrower => {
            res.status(200).send(borrower)
            book.update({
              count: book.count - 1,
            });
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            return res.status(400).send(e)
          })
      }
    });
},
```

To return a book I have the following:

```
returnBooks(req, res) {
  Book.findOne({
      where: {
        title: req.body.title,
        author: req.body.author,
      }
    })
    .then((book) => {
      if (!book) {
        return res.status(400).send({
          message: "There is no book like that!"
        })
      } else {
        book.update({
          count: book.count + 1,
        })
        Borrower.findOne({
            where: {
              id: req.params.userId,
              booktitle: req.body.title,
            }
          })
          .then((returnedBook) => {
            returnedBook.update({
                returnDate: Date.now()
              })
              .then(() => res.status(200).send({
                message: "book successfully returned",
                returnedBook
              }))
          })
      }
    })
}
```

This works ok (i think) for one book, but if a user borrows 2 or more books and i try to return them, it does not work.

How can it work so that it would return more instance of a borrowed book. How can it notice the new id of the new book borrowed?

If i try to return a second book, it throws the following error?

```
Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of null
    at Borrower.findOne.then (C:\Users\okonjiemmanuel\Desktop\hellobooks\server\controllers\book.js:142:23)
    at tryCatcher (C:\Users\okonjiemmanuel\Desktop\hellobooks\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\okonjiemmanuel\Desktop\hellobooks\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.
js:512:
```

Comment: Please someone should help me out

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using .findAll?

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-findAll

```
Book.findAll({
  where: {
    title: req.body.title,
    author: req.body.author
  }
})
```

depending on if you want to use the instance model or raw values, you'll have to pass some options. ie: raw: true